# Nonlinear equation $6 + \sinh(x) = \sinh(3x)$

Tags: nonlinear-analysis

I have this equation

- $6 + \sinh(x) = \sinh(3x)$

I know that I have to use this equation

- $\sinh(3x) = 3\sinh(x) + 4\sinh^3(x)$
- and substitution

Can anybody please help me? thx

Comment: already edited :)

Comment: You say you know what $\sinh(3x)$ is. What's stopping you from using that? And you say you have to use substitution. What substitution seems sensible to you? What's stopping you from doing that substitution?

Comment: What have you tried? An immediate method comes to mind, but I want to know if you’ve tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\sinh(x)$. Then $\sinh(3x)=4t^3+3t$. So your equation becomes
$$
6+t = 4t^3+3t,
$$
$$
4t^3+2t-6=0,
$$
$$
(2t-2)(2t^2+2t+3)=0.
$$
If a product of two factors is zero, then at least one of the factors must be zero:
$$
2t-2=0 \quad\mbox{ or }\quad 2t^2+2t+3=0.
$$
The first factor gives us a real solution
$$t=1, \quad \sinh x=1, \quad x=\sinh^{-1}(1)=\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\approx0.88137.
$$
The second factor does not give us real solutions t (but there are complex ones).

Comment: Yea, I got exactly there and then I do not know what else to do

Comment: How did you come to those two factors? That is my obstacle.

Comment: You can always use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+2t%5E3%2Bt-3)

Comment: yea but if you have to write on paper without any helper :)

Comment: Please refer to [SparkNotes](https://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra2/polynomials/section4/) explanation how to factor a polynomial to (x-root1)(x-root2)... "by hand"

Comment: yea, now I see, same technique which is used in linear algebra - horner's scheme, didnt realize I can use it there too :-)

Comment: I have one (maybe stupid) question. If I take prescription for sinh(x), put in 1 and then make its exponent -1 and finally get 0.850 Why it is not similar to derived prescription of argsinh(x)?

Comment: The exponent -1 in f^{-1}(x) means: the inverse function of f. This notation is actually used; e.g. WolframAlpha understands both sinh^(-1)(1) and arsinh(1). But a special thing about hyperbolic functions sinh, cosh, ... is that they are expressed in terms of exp(x) - and their inverses are expressed in terms of ln(...). For example, in this question, arsinh(1) = ln(1+sqrt(2))